# Different type constraints for the same instance

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm defining my own complex number data type as a learning exercise, and I've run into trouble overloading `abs` along with the other members of `Num`. As far as I know, only one instance definition is allowed per typeclass, but if I could I'd do something like this:

```
instance Num a => Num (Complex a) where
    (+) (Complex ra ia) (Complex rb ib) = Complex (ra + rb) (ia + ib)
    (-) (Complex ra ia) (Complex rb ib) = Complex (ra - rb) (ia - ib)
    (*) (Complex ra ia) (Complex rb ib) = Complex (ra*rb - ia*ib) (ra*ib + rb*ia)
    fromInteger r = Complex (fromInteger r) 0

instance Floating a => Num (Complex a) where
    abs (Complex r i) = Complex (sqrt $ r^2 + i^2) 0
```

or

```
instance Floating a => Floating (Complex a) where
    abs (Complex r i) = Complex (sqrt $ r^2 + i^2) 0
```

Because none of the members other than `abs` require `Floating` types, and I don't want to limit them to only `Floating` types, but the `abs` function is super important, and I don't want to unnecessarily exclude it.
Is there some way I can have the functions `(+)`, `(-)`, and `(*)` work on all numeric types, while still implementing `abs`?

According to [7.6.3.4. Overlapping instances](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html) in the GHC system guide, multiple instances can overlap if they differ on the type constraint(?) outside of the context (eg `instance C [a]` and `instance C [Int]`), with the compiler choosing the most specific instance for a given case, but it doesn't mention anything about only the context differing (eg `instance C [a]` and `instance Integral a => C [a]`).

Comment: Sadly, the typeclass hierarchy for "numbers" (or "basic algebra stuff", or whatever one should call it) was quite badly thought out from the beginning. Maybe you are better off sidestepping it completely for your `Complex a`? There exists [an alternative hierarchy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude), but it's maybe a bit overkill for your situation.

Said differently: You seem to want a principled way to make a typeclass for complex numbers. The standard typeclasses like `Num` that you are wanting to work with are very ad-hoc :-(

Comment: @gspr: the number hierarchy may not be optimal, but in practice it works quite fine. As far as this use case is concerned – in almost all real-world applications of complex numbers, you would require `Floating` anyway; complex numbers are mostly useful in a context of roots and/or exponentials (to describe oscillations).

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Agreed, although one might imagine a practical and useful instance for `Ratio Integer` too.

Comment: @gspr while such numbers _can_ make sense, they aren't adequately represented by `Data.Complex.Complex Rational`. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cyclotomic has a proper implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main source of pain here is that the Prelude's number hierarchy was defined to not be too complex - for most things, it works just fine. This is one of those edge cases where is doesn't really (although as @leftaroundabout points out, I'm not sure there are many applications for a `Complex` over something that is *not* `Floating`).

Your options are to

- Add a `Floating a` constraint on `Num (Complex a)`. This is what feels most natural to me and makes the most sense from a type class perspective - shoehorning in `instance Num a => Num (Complex a)` breaks the `Num` abstraction because it has no notion of `abs`.
- Use a finer-grain numeric hierarchy. The [`numeric-prelude`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude-0.4.2) comes to mind. In that, you will find the following (spread out over multiple modules):

  ```
  class (Field.C a) => Algebraic.C a where
    sqrt :: a -> a

  class (Ring.C a) => Field.C a where
    (/)           :: a -> a -> a
    recip         :: a -> a
    fromRational' :: Rational -> a
    (^-)          :: a -> Integer -> a

  class (Ring.C a) => Absolute.C a where
    abs    :: a -> a
    signum :: a -> a

  class (Additive.C a) => Ring.C a where
    (*)         :: a -> a -> a
    one         :: a
    fromInteger :: Integer -> a 
    (^)         :: a -> Integer -> a

  class Additive.C a where
    zero     :: a
    (+), (-) :: a -> a -> a
    negate   :: a -> a
  ```

  In your case, you would be making instances `instance Additive.C a => Additive.C (Complex a)`, `instance Ring.C a => Ring.C (Complex a)`, and `instance Algebraic.C a => Absolute.C (Complex a)`.
- If I haven't yet managed to convince you to abandon this madness, feel free to check out [this page on advanced overlap](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap). Aside from being complex and boilerplate heavy (and needing to turn on a ton of language extensions), this solution isn't quite general (you'll still have to hand-pick which types go to which instance).